# UnsatisfiedLinkError in packaged .jar

Tags: java, dll, jar

I've got a program that's packaged as a .jar I need to run for school. In essence the program acts as an interface between a user and a DC motor to control speed, angle, etc.

This program (which required MS C++ to install) runs well on everyone's machines running win7 or 8, but not on my XP_x64 machine. When opened from the start menu, it spawns multiple javaw.exe processes, but no application is created. Run from command line, I find this:

```
C:\Program Files\Quanser\QICii_USB\bin>java -jar usbQICii.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load     library: C
:\Program Files\Quanser\QICii_USB\bin\lib\usbQICii_jni.dll
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.quanser.raskin.QIC_USB.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at com.quanser.conduit.pic.PICSource.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.quanser.raskin.RaskinFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.quanser.raskin.Raskin.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.quanser.raskin.Raskin.main(Unknown Source)
```

I've so far been unable to locate the requested .dll on my system. Two primary questions: is there something obvious I've missed? If I could find the .dll on someone else' machine (so far a no-go) could I grab it and use it on mine (x64 compatibility pending, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Check where usbQICii_jni.dll is located.
My guess is that it is in
    "C:\Program Files\Quanser\QICii_USB\lib"
If I'm right, go one directory up, and form
    "C:\Program Files\Quanser\QICii_USB"
execute
    "java -jar bin\usbQICii.jar"